Can sun dried tomatoes be eaten without rehydrating?
In article I read that kids eat sun dried tomatoes as a snack.
I’m other places I read that sun dried tomatoes need to be rehydrated before being eaten.  I assume this applies to both those completely dry and those in oil.
So can they actually be eaten completely dry without rehydrating or what was the article referring to when it said kids eat them as a snack - did they mean those in oil?
Thanks.

I put them in sandwitches dry. I have never heard that I need to rehydrate them

Have you never seen dehydrated fruits? Those can be eaten as-is. Can you link to the article?

I eat them (dried, no oil) as a snack. I'm fairly obsolete as being a child goes.
Depending what I'm making I may also rehydrate them to an extent (balsamic vinegar rather than water can be nice for that; again, depending what I'm making.)
I'm not overly fond of traditional cooked tomato sauce or paste, but ground-up dried tomatoes and balsamic vinegar makes a very nice tapenade if you can get past the traditional definition of tapenade.
Rather than canning loads of sauce or paste when tomatoes are ripening in hordes, I run my dehydrator like mad, so I have a fairly good quantity of dried on hand at most times.

To OPs specific question: there is nothing unsafe about eating sundried tomates without hydrating them. Whether you like the flavor and what dishes they work in is up to personal preference.

Beef Jerky comes to mind. Like tomatoes, it too starts out full of moisture before being dried. It is then eaten in it's dried state. There are also a plethora of other dried fruits... from raisins, to various types of "fruit leather". Which is delicious and kind of like jerky made from fruit. Some dried goods are dryer than others though. Dried mushrooms for example. Which aren't very pleasant to eat due to their texture. There's dried banana chips come to think of it.
So the question of whether kids can eat sun-dried tomatoes as snacks, comes down to how tough they are to actually eat.
As for what type of sun-dried tomatoes the article was referring to, no one can really answer that without you providing a link to the article.

Jerky is dried slices of meat so directly equivalent to raisins or dried slices of apple, not at all like fruit leather (apart from texture), which is a dried mash of the fruit. Banana chips are usually fried or partially dried and then fried so not really a dried product

The point I was making was that they are all low moisture products that are eaten as is, without needing to be re-hydrated. So the fact that some sun-dried tomatoes are dry, isn't an issue. What is an issue, is how easy and pleasant they are to eat. Also, not all banana chips are fried, and like other dried fruits, they can be crunchy and crisp, or soft an chewy depending on how they were made.
